# Server connection and current connection are different on Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

The orange rectangles indicate two different databases within the current instances.  Why are they different - what do both of them indicate?

- "ddexdev" on the right seems to be the active connection
- Is the "test_db" on the leftnav just misleading - it's not the currently connected database? If so then what is its purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leftnav and the query panel *are* different, that's confusing. Here is what to do:

- Right click on the leftnav selected connection and  click 'Edit connecction'

[image]

- Choose the intended database from the dropdown:

[image]

The database in leftnav now is synchronized with the query window:

[image]